# How do you reference related models' fields in the admin list_filter?

Tags: django, django-admin

My Models:

OrderInfo is one-to-one with Print, which is a Many-to-One with Painting, which itself is a Many-to-One with Club.

```
class OrderInfo(models.Model):
    print_ordered = models.OneToOneField(Print, blank=True)

class Print(models.Model):
    painting = models.ForeignKey(Painting)

class Painting(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
```

In my OrderInfoAdmin, I'd like to be able to sort by the related Club, but I can't figure out the syntax to do this.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
class OrderInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['print_ordered__painting__club']
```

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you figure it out, please post back. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list_filter` command is for filtering not ordering. You want the `ordering` command which is documented here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering. It's not clear to me though from the documentation if the `modeling` Meta command allows ordering through foreign keys. (The `filter()` queryset function definitely does: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields)

I've found the admin has some limitations working with deeply hierarchical models. For example, you can inline a child model on its parent's page, but you can't inline an grandchild. Also, by default the `list_filter` command only works on fields in the modeled table. In your example, you couldn't filter on the fields of `Print` in the `OrderInfo` admin for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just today, Josh VanderLinden posted a solution for this on his blog:

[Model Relationships and "list_display"](http://www.codekoala.com:4000/posts/model-relationships-and-list_display/)

(Found via [Django Community](http://www.djangoproject.com/community/))